# Optimizing the code for error minimization

Tags: r, optimization

I have written the code below for minimization of error by changing the value of alpha (using iteration method).

```
set.seed(16)
npoints = 10000
Y = round(runif(npoints), 3)
OY = sample(c(0, 1, 0.5), npoints, replace = T)

minimizeAlpha = function(Y, OY, alpha) {
    PY = alpha*Y
    error = OY - PY
    squaredError = sapply(error, function(x) x*x)
    sse = sum(squaredError)
    return(sse)
}
# # Iterate for 10000 values
alphas = seq(0.0001, 1, 0.0001)
sse = sapply(alphas, function(x) minimizeAlpha(Y, OY, x))
print(alphas[sse == min(sse)])
```

I have used `sapply` for basic optimization. But, if the number of points are more than 10000 this code is running forever. So, is there any better way of implementation or any standard techniques to optimize (like `Bisection`). If so can you please help me in optimizing the code.

**Note**: I need the value of alpha with at least 4 decimals.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You may get some efficiency with `vapply` and using the return value i.e. `vapply(alpphas, function(x) minimizeAlpha(Y, OY, x), numeric(1))`

Comment: Should look at [codereview.se]

Comment: Replacing `for` by `sapply` isn’t an optimisation, that’s a misunderstanding.

Comment: @akrun - `sse = vapply(alphas, FUN = function(x) minimizeAlpha(Y, OY, x), FUN.VALUE = 0.0)`. Still the code is running for ever. Is this the right syntax?

Comment: I said some efficiency wrt to `sapply` but not that much.  Otherwise, one option may be to replicate the alphas by the length of 'Y', 'OY' and viceversa and apply the function along with replacing the `sapply` within the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `sapply` instead of `for` isn’t more efficient, [that’s a misconception](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/4xf27q/whats_stopping_the_r_community_from_fixing_the/). It’s merely often simpler code.

However, you can actually take advantage of vectorisation in your code — and that *would* be faster.

For instance, `sapply(error, function(x) x*x)` can simply be replaced by `x * x`. The sum of squared errors of numbers in R is thus simply `sum((OY - PY) ** 2)`.

Your whole function thus boils down to:

```
minimizeAlpha = function(Y, OY, alpha)
    sum((OY - alpha * Y) ** 2)
```

This should be more efficient — but first and foremost it’s better code and more readable.

Comment: Great. This works like a charm. Just to increase my understanding, was it `sapply(error, function(x) x*x)` this line that is taking time? Also if npoints are increased further even this takes time. So, I have heard that there are some standards like `Bisection` methods to solve such problems? Am I on the right path?

Comment: @KartheekPalepu Yes, the `sapply` line essentially tears an efficient C operation into parts and runs more (slow) code in R rather than in C. Regarding your second question, you’re on the right path. Also take a look at the `optimize` and `optim` functions that implement advanced strategies for this.